# Give an example of three events A, B and C such that $Pr(A \mid B) > Pr(A)$ and $Pr(A \mid C) > Pr(A)$ but $ Pr(A \mid B ∪ C) < Pr(A)$

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have found examples that give equality in the last of the three, but not sure no luck on strict inequality- any hints/ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

suppose the universe is the set of numbers $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ with equal probability.

define:  $$A=\{1,\;4\}\;\;\&\;\;B=\{1,\;2\}\;\;\&\;\;C=\{1,\;3\}$$

Then $P(A)=\frac 25$, $P(A|B)=\frac 12=P(A|C)$.

But $B\cup C=\{1,\;2,\;3\}$ so $P(A|B\cup C)=\frac 13<\frac 25$